# how to move char right ? After restriction I have no idea. Could anyone writes on the comments?

Tags: java

You are allowed to use the following methods from the Java API:

class String:
length,charAt

class StringBuilder:
length,charAt,append,toString

class Character: any method

moveAllXsRight takes a char and a String as input and returns a String.
The output string should be the same as the input string except that every occurrence of the input character should be shifted one character to the right. If it is impossible to shift a character to the right (it is at the end of the string), then it is not shifted. Do not use arrays to solve this problem.

> HW2.moveAllXsRight('X', "abcXdeXXXfghXiXXjXX")
>   "abcdXefXXXghiXjXXXX"

Here is my code now:

```
public static String moveAllXsRight(char a, String b){
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
     String str ="";
     for ( int i = 0; i<b.length(); i++){
          if(b.charAt(i) != a){
              sb.append(b.charAt(i));
          }

         else if(b.charAt(i) == a){

              str = Character.toString(b.charAt(i));                 
         }

         else {
              if(b.charAt(i+2)>sb.length()){
                sb.append(b.charAt(i));
              }

              }
     }

     return sb.toString();
 }
```

Comment: Why wouldn't `"abcdXeXXfXghiXXjXXX"` be a correct result?

Comment: Or `"abcdefXXXghiXjXXXXX"`

Comment: yes, it is a correct result, but I don't know how to move x one character to the right. That's why  I am here to get some thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static String moveAllXsRight(char a, String b) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(b);

    for(int i = 0; i < sb.length() - 1; i++) {
        if(sb.charAt(i) == a) {
            // swapping with the right character
            sb.setCharAt(i, sb.charAt(i + 1));
            sb.setCharAt(i + 1, a);
            // skipping next index (because we already know it contains `a`)
            i = i + 1;
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

For this example:

```
moveAllXsRight('X', "abcXdeXXXfghXiXXjXX");
```

This is the output:

```
abcdXeXXfXghiXXXjXX
```

**Update:**

By slightly changing the `for` loop (inverting it):

```
for(int i = sb.length() - 2; i > 0; i--) { // inverse loop
    if(sb.charAt(i) == a) {
        // swapping
        sb.setCharAt(i, sb.charAt(i + 1));
        sb.setCharAt(i + 1, a);
    }
}
```

Now this:

```
moveAllXsRight('X', "abcXdeXXXfghXiXXjXX");
```

Results in:

```
abcdXefXXXghiXjXXXX
```

> Now you can decide which version do you want to use.

Comment: I will take some time to understand, I only learn java for 1 month , thanks!!!

Comment: @HaomiaoShi sure, no problem.

Comment: From my understand,  You use the value in index i+1 to replace the value in index i. Then, you replace the value in the i+1 index with a. Our professor never talks about this setCharAt() method, but he mentions set,get, CharAt methods. I think it may be allowed for this task. Otherwise I will confuse again because of the restriction.

Comment: @HaomiaoShi `charAt(index)` returns the `char` at that `index`. You can say that it is a getter method. `setChar(index, value)` is the setter method that sets the `value` at the `index`.

Comment: @HaomiaoShi I have also provided an **Update** in my answer. Here the loop is reversed. Instead of looping from `0`th index, we start from the end side of the `String` to `0` index, this way the output is a little different. Please check which version suits your need then use it accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: @HaomiaoShi You can take as much time as you want. If it fulfills your requirement then you can accept my answer otherwise don't. I hope it helps you. Thanks.

Comment: The reverse direction is really excellent which gives me a new thinking way to write a method.

Comment: I use the first one.

Comment: @HaomiaoShi I am glad that my answer helped you. Please consider accepting my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @HaomiaoShi there is a **Tick** mark near the answer. If you click it (it will turn to green) it will be accepted. You can read: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: I follow your link to accept the answer, It really easy to understand and straightforward.

Comment: @HaomiaoShi Yes, it is. Welcome to StackOverflow community. You will understand more things about it with the passage of time. Thank you for accepting my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
public static String moveAllXsRight(char a, String b) {
    char[] chars = b.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length-1; ++i) {
        if (chars[i] == a) {
            chars[i] = chars[i+1];
            chars[i+1] = a;
        }
    }
    return new String(chars);
}
```

It gives `"abcdeXXXfghXiXXjXXX"` when the arguments are `'X'` and `"abcXdeXXXfghXiXXjXX"`.

Here's another way:

```
public static String moveAllXsRight(char a, String b) {
    char[] chars = b.toCharArray();
    boolean wasa = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; ++i) {
        char c = chars[i];
        if (wasa) {
            chars[i-1] = c;
            chars[i] = a;
        }
        wasa = c == a;
    }
    return new String(chars);
}
```

It gives `"abcdXeXXfXghiXXjXXX"`.

UPDATE

Here's yet another way:

```
public static String moveAllXsRight(char a, String b) {
    char[] chars = b.toCharArray();
    for (int i = chars.length-1; --i >= 0;) {
        char c = chars[i];
        if (c == a) {
            chars[i] = chars[i+1];
            chars[i+1] = a;
        }
    }
    return new String(chars);
}
```

It gives `"abcdXefXXXghiXjXXXX"` which is what you expected.

UPDATE 2:

With a `StringBuilder` to avoid using arrays:

```
public static String moveAllXsRight(char a, String b) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(b);
    for (int i = buf.length()-1; --i >= 0;) {
        char c = buf.charAt(i);
        if (c == a) {
            buf.setCharAt(i, buf.charAt(i+1));
            buf.setCharAt(i+1, a);
        }
    }
    return buf.toString();
}
```

Comment: Please gives me sometimes to read carefully even if the arr is restricted but still a good idea to understand in the other thinking way.

Answer (score -2):

```
public static String moveAllXsRight(char a, String b){
    String str ="";
    int n = 0;
    char lower_a = Character.toLowerCase(a);
    char upper_a = Character.toUpperCase(a);

    for ( int i = b.length()-2; i>=0; i--){
        if(b.charAt(i) == lower_a || b.charAt(i) == upper_a){
            n++;
        }
    }

    str = b.substring(b.length()-n) + b.substring(0,b.length()-n);
    return str;
}
```

Comment: First, it not works.  Second,  our professor says we can not use subString() in this method